# Update SQL Server .net version

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-clr

I have used [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to detect the latest install `.net` version and here is the result:

[image]

Its `.net 4.0` and I want to know if the `SQL Server` is using the latest installed version?

I want to create `CLR` function using `.net 4.5` and the `SQL Server` must use this version either. If I install `4.5` version, will the server automatically start using it?

Comment: .NET 4.5 is a binary replacement for 4.0 which means it replaces the actual 4.0 binaries. There is no v4.5 folder.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Check the version - of this folder - it is 4.0